# R, How does while (TRUE) work?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I have to write a function of the following method :

*Rejection method (uniform envelope)*:

Suppose that fx is non-zero only on [a, b], and fx ≤ k.

1. Generate X ∼ U(a, b) and Y ∼ U(0, k) independent of X (so P =
   (X, Y ) is uniformly distributed over the rectangle [a, b] × [0, k]).
2. If Y < fx(x) then return X, otherwise go back to step 1.

   ```
   rejectionK <- function(fx, a, b, K) {
       # simulates from the pdf fx using the rejection algorithm
       # assumes fx is 0 outside [a, b] and bounded by K
       # note that we exit the infinite loop using the return statement

       while (TRUE) {
         x <- runif(1, a, b)
         y <- runif(1, 0, K)
         if (y < fx(x)) return(x)
      }
   }
   ```

I have not understood why is this `TRUE` in  `while (TRUE)` ?

if (y < fx(x)) is not true then the method suggests to repeat the loop again to generate the uniform number again. (y < fx(x)) is not true=FALSE. So why will not the condition be `while (FALSE)`?

Again in which basis will i get enter into the  while loop ? That is, i am accustomed with this

```
   a=5 
   while(a<7){
      a=a+1
   }
```

here i define a before writing the condition (a<7) .

But in `while (TRUE)` , which statement is true ?

Additionally:

you can run the codes

```
  rejectionK <- function(fx, a, b, K) {
        # simulates from the pdf fx using the rejection algorithm
        # assumes fx is 0 outside [a, b] and bounded by K
        # note that we exit the infinite loop using the return statement

        while (TRUE) {
          x <- runif(1, a, b)
          y <- runif(1, 0, K)
          cat("y=",y,"fx=",fx(x),"",y < fx(x),"\n")
          if (y < fx(x)) return(x)
       }
    }

  fx<-function(x){
     # triangular density
     if ((0<x) && (x<1)) {
       return(x)
     } else if ((1<x) && (x<2)) {
       return(2-x)
     } else {
       return(0)
     }
 }

 set.seed(123)
 rejectionK(fx, 0, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an infinite loop. The expression is executed as long as the condition evaluates to `TRUE`, which it will always do. However, in the expression there is a `return`, which when called (e.g., if `y < fx(x)`), breaks out of the function and thus stops the loop.

Here is a simpler example:

```
fun <- function(n) {
  i <- 1
  while (TRUE) {
    if (i>n) return("stopped") else print(i)
    i <- i+1
  }
}

fun(3)
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] "stopped"
```

What happens when this function is called?

1. `i` is set to 1.
2. The condition of the `while` loop is tested. Because it is `TRUE`, it's expression is evaluated.
3. The condition of the `if` construct is tested. Since it is `FALSE` the `else` expression is evaluated and `i` is printed.
4. `i` is increased by 1.
5. Steps 3 and 4 are repeated.
6. When `i` reaches the value of 4, the condition of the `if` construct is `TRUE` and `return("stopped")` is evaluated. This stops the whole function and returns the value "stopped".

Comment: i apologize. I have not understood yet. Which statement need to be TRUE? i>n or i<n ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: when i=1 why will i enter the loop ? 1 is not greater than 3 so this is FALSE and i need to repeat the loop until it returns "stopped". hence Why is not the  condition `while(FALSE)` so that i can get enter the loop.

Comment: You're missing the point, think of `while(TRUE)` as `while(TRUE==TRUE)`, i.e. continue regardless

Comment: FYI, R actually has the keyword `repeat` which is perhaps a more clear version of `while(TRUE)` (although honestly it seems very rarely used)

Answer (score 5):

Inside while loop, if we have return statement with true or false.. it will work accordingly..

Example: To Check a list is circular or not..

here the loop is infinite, because while (true) is true always, but we can break sometimes by using the return statement,.

```
while(true)
{
if(!faster || !faster->next)
return false;
else
if(faster==slower || faster->next=slower)
{
printf("the List is Circular\n");
break;
}
else
{
slower = slower->next;
faster = faster->next->next;
}
```

Comment: for mentioning the use of `break`