# Prefab doesnot activate when collide with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a project and there is a problem that I am facing.

I have two gameObject with 2D colliders (coming from a prefab) which moves right to left. When they touch each other they deactivate.

I also have an empty game object in which i add a script `Respawner` which randomly generates obstacles.

The problem is when they touch each other once, they never get re-activated again.

Respawner Empty GameObject :

[image]

Border :

[image]

Prefabs :
[image]
Respawn Script:

```
public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] obstacles;
    private List<GameObject> listname = new List<GameObject>();

    void Awake(){
        InitilizeObstacle();
    }

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());
    }

    void InitilizeObstacle(){
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<obstacles.Length * 3 ; i++) {
            GameObject obj  = Instantiate(obstacles[index],new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,-2f),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            listname.Add(obj);

            listname[i].SetActive(false);
            index++;

            if(index==obstacles.Length){
                index =0;
            }
        }
    }

    void shuffle(){
        for (int i=0; i<listname.Count; i++) {
            GameObject temp = listname [i];
            int random = Random.Range (i, listname.Count);
            listname [i] = listname [random];
            listname [random] = temp;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RandomObstacleSpawn(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1.5f,2.5f));

        int index = Random.Range (0, listname.Count);
        while (true) {
            if(!listname[index].activeInHierarchy){
                listname[index].SetActive(true);
                listname[index].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,-2f);

                break;
            } else {
                index = Random.Range(0,listname.Count);
            }

            StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());
        }
    }
}
```

Script attach to prefab for move:

```
public class ObstacleMove : MonoBehaviour {
    private float speed = -1.25f;

    void Start() { }

    void Update() {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = pos;   
    }
}
```

Scripts attach to prefab for touch border:

```
public class BorderTouch : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
            if(target.tag=="Border"){
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite a few details missing here. I don't see anything that would reactivate the obstacle. You also call RandomObstacleSpawn but you don't show it. I assume the problem is in there

Comment: @fafase in random spawn script `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` will generate random obstacles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer based on new question:**

If you want to make things happen AFTER the collision. Put a script on Border:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class borderListener : MonoBehaviour {
        public Respawn rS;

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
                rS.spawnIt ();

        }

}
```

On Unity Editor, drag the Respawn object to the Border Script on hierarchy.
Do not skip this step or things won't work!

On Respawn script, remove the last `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` line on `IEnumerator RandomObstacleSpawn()` method. And create a public method (to access from other script) *anywhere* inside Respawn script:

```
public void spawnIt(){
                StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());
        }
```

**Old answer based on old code:**

From what I see on your package:

```
    while (true) { //A
                if(!listname[index].activeInHierarchy){
                       //B
                    listname[index].SetActive(true);
                    listname[index].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,-2f);

                    break; //C
                } else {
                    index = Random.Range(0,listname.Count);
                }

                StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn()); //D
            }
```

I am a lil noob, I will try my best to help. But this piece of code makes me wonder:
`while(true)` what? what is true? (EDIT: found some observation bellow)

The code seem to do this path:
Go inside the while loop (A)

Go at the first option in if statement (B)

Go to the line break; (C)

Never reaches the StartCoroutine (D) > **that is why it does not activate again.**

If you try and put a `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` before the `break;` you probably will get an Unity crash. What if you take off the while statement at all? You need to adjust time of yield tho.

This is the code I would use:

```
IEnumerator RandomObstacleSpawn(){

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(3.5f,4.5f));
            int index = Random.Range (0, listname.Count);


            if(!listname[index].activeInHierarchy){
                listname[index].SetActive(true);
                listname[index].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,-2f);

            }else{

                index = Random.Range(0,listname.Count);

            }

             StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());
        }
```

EDIT: about the while(true) I've manage to find more information about this concept here: [R, How does while (TRUE) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942299/r-how-does-while-true-work) 
But still... the `break;` on the code is really making the Access to `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` unreachable .

Comment: now obstacles are generating on after collision but both obstacles are moving at same time

Comment: the collision has not to do with it. it is timed! What generate the obstacles is the Coroutine, not collision. That is how your code is oriented.

Comment: is there a way that i can do this when one is collide then second obstacle activate

Comment: The `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` is inside the while(true) so it is executed unless the `break` triggers. By the way, this is C# and not R. Anyways, that coroutine is a major flaw in his code with the `While(true)` since `activeInHierarchy` will always return true if he does not use `SetActive(false)`.

Comment: @ForceMagic yeah. I would not use Coroutine at all.

Comment: @ゴスエンヘンリ    where i put this function public void spawnIt() in `Respawner Script` and does also remove the  `StartCoroutine(RandomObstacleSpawn());` at start method

Comment: @ゴスエンヘンリ  if i put this method on line `IEnumerator RandomObstacleSpawn()` then coroutine will remove but your spawnIt method also contain coroutine

Comment: 1- Put the spawnIt() anywhere on Respawn script. Is a common method. 2- No, do not remove, keep the StartCouroutine line at Start() or the first obstacle will not appear. You just gonna remove the StartCouroutine line that is inside IEnumerator. This will remove the automatic factor. Your code is Coroutine oriented. I would use a simple Invoke() with random time. BUT I don't know what is your need. I just make the call of the Coroutine OUTSIDE the Coroutine - it will trigger after collisions. That is what you need, uh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98127/discussion-between-mann-deep-and--).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is fairly common, when the following code is executed `gameObject.SetActive(false);` it deactivate everything on that gameObject.

Thus, the next time they would have collided will never be triggered.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve for the behaviour, but if you just want to hide the gameObjects you could disable the Renderer component instead.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enable = false;
```

And switch it to true when needed.

That's why  we must be carefull when we use `SetActive(false)` on `gameObject` in Unity.

Comment: @MannDeep Updated my answer since I misunderstood a detail at first and I also assumed that you'd want to hide the game object when they touch the Border.

Comment: You also need to deactivate the collider.

Comment: @ForceMagic  i'm facing a problem you can see on this package https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnTFRjYWN5SzUzOXc